# Problem with LTR and RTL in Flutter with Easy localization

Tags: flutter, localization

I'm new in flutter and I think I changed something I shouldn't have. I was working with easy_localization package and I remember changing a file which contained an array like this:

```
[
  'ar', // Arabic
  'fa', // Farsi
  'he', // Hebrew
  'ps', // Pashto
  'ur', // Urdu
];
```

I thought it was the languages file and did add 'en' and 'de' in it. I now cannot find the file to roll back that change since I've learned it's something about the languages direction; rtl, ltr, etc....

For example, my current language is en and my first 3 inputs text go rtl. Now with the question mark at the end of the text down in the picture.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/Snt56.png

If I make a new language like fr everything goes to ltr again normally. I want to know what I changed. I cant find the file anywhere and I don't know if it's even related to the easy_localization package.

Also I made a new project and copied only the files in lib folder with assets folder and the problem seem to still be around.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had to reinstall the flutter sdk with dart and make a new project for it to work normally again.